# C++ interface between raw pointers and shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have code that uses raw pointers throughout.

It needs to call a method that takes the raw pointer into a shared_ptr.
This method is not under my control, belonging to an external api.
I cannot just pass the pointer to the shared_ptr because when it will be deleted
when the shared_ptr goes out of scope in the method (when the method returns).

Do I have any option other than making my raw pointer a shared_ptr in my internal code?

Comment: Why does your code use raw pointers throughout?

Comment: Its not my code. Its the company's code that I now own/maintain. Is it  a worthwhile goal to move pointers to shared_ptrs throughout ? Opinions ?

Comment: @user: Depends on your situation. If you could make the code safer, faster, and cleaner, and have time for it, you should fix all code. But sometimes you just need to run with what you have, and improve it from there. In other words, focus on what you need to get done, and when you have time fix and upgrade old, broken code. (Unless, of course, you can't continue *because* the code is broken with raw pointers, then obviously fix it.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sounds somewhat unusual and potentially quite dangerous, but you can accomplish this by using a no-op deleter when constructing the `shared_ptr`:

```
struct no_op_delete
{
    void operator()(void*) { }
};

int* p = 0; // your pointer
std::shared_ptr<int> sp(p, no_op_delete());
```

When `sp` and all copies that were made of it have been destroyed, `no_op_delete` will be invoked to clean up the held pointer.  Since it does nothing, you get the behavior you need.

Comment: James McNellis never sleeps xD .

Comment: @Prasoon:  Sleep just wastes time I could otherwise spend programming.

Answer (score 1):

James had already answered the question. So, this is merely a suggestion. If you know that the function call doesn't modify the object (like setting some data members etc.), you could create a new object from your raw pointer and pass that via a shared_ptr to the function. That way, you assume that the function takes ownership of the object and does whatever is required. Of course this doesn't work if the function will modify the object in it. This can work if the function uses the object as a read-only to do some other operation (like file I/O for e.g.)