# How to get shared_ptr from raw pointer?

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault

I'm doing c/c++ mix programming, like this:
common.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
typedef opentracing::Span CTraceSpan;
#else
struct CTraceSpan;
typedef struct CTraceSpan CTraceSpan;
#endif

extern "C" CTraceSpan* c_StartServerSpan();
extern "C" CTraceSpan* c_FinishServerSpan(CTraceSpan *span);
```

trace2c.cpp

```
extern "C" CTraceSpan* c_StartServerSpan(){
auto server_span = hwtrace::StartServerSpan();
return server_span.get();
}  

extern "C" CTraceSpan* c_FinishServerSpan(CTraceSpan *span){
std::shared_ptr<opentracing::Span> s_span(std::move(span));

auto server_span = hwtrace::FinishServerSpan(s_span);
return server_span.get();
}
```

and in trace.c

```
CTraceSpan *span = NULL;
span = c_StartClientSpan();
c_FinishClientSpan(span);
```

when I run my project, I got an error:

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

the question below, said that can't create shared_ptr from an raw pointer, but I need to transmit a pointer form c to c++, what should i do?

[Segmentation fault when using a shared_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670842/segmentation-fault-when-using-a-shared-ptr)

> You should never create shared_ptr from an ordinary pointer as you do here:
>
> ```
> shared_ptr<ParticleEmitter>(&e)
> ```
>
> This tries to free the ParticleEmitter twice. Once as the vector holding the ParticleEmitter objects goes out of scope, and once as the shared_ptr goes out of scope.

Comment: `std::move` on a pointer is meaningless ;)

Comment: You don't move a pointer. If you want to take ownership over `span` pointer, you simply construct `std::shared_ptr` with it (or better - use `std::make_shared` if using C++14). Segmentation fault is probably because somebody else *also* wants to manage that pointer. Is it `free`d anywhere in the code?

Comment: I would avoid writing code that can be compiled by 2 compilers like that.  it looks like a maintenance nightmare.  Write the implementation in a single c++ library, and then if you want to use it in C you write a collection of extern C wrappers around the functions you want to call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are already `shared_ptr`s owing those `CTraceSpan`s, you can't create a new `shared_ptr` from the raw pointer. Otherwise you would have two ownership relations to the `CTraceSpan`, and undefined behaviour after one of them frees the `CTraceSpan`.

The implementation of `c_FinishServerSpan` is going to have to have to go find an *existing* `std::shared_ptr<CTraceSpan>`, such that it's underlying pointer is equal to `span`.

```
static std::map<CTraceSpan*, std::shared_ptr<CTraceSpan>> spans;

extern "C" CTraceSpan* c_StartServerSpan(){
    auto server_span = hwtrace::StartServerSpan();
    spans[server_span.get()] = server_span;
    return server_span.get();
}  

extern "C" CTraceSpan* c_FinishServerSpan(CTraceSpan *span){
    auto s_span = spans.at(span);
    // spans.erase(span) ?

    auto server_span = hwtrace::FinishServerSpan(s_span);
    spans[server_span.get()] = server_span;
    return server_span.get();
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks very much.  And answer by @James McNellis in question below also works. 
 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526224/how-to-get-shared-ptr-from-raw-pointer/50527259#50527259



    `struct no_op_delete
    {
        void operator()(void*) { }
    };

    int* p = 0; // your pointer
    std::shared_ptr<int> sp(p, no_op_delete());`

Comment: sorry, link is this   
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486048/c-interface-between-raw-pointers-and-shared-ptr?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

> the question below, said that can't create shared_ptr from an raw pointer

That particular answer is wrong in general (although correct in that specific case). You *can* create a shared pointer from a raw pointer. You just can't create a shared pointer from a pointer that doesn't own the object.

> but I need to transmit a pointer form c to c++, what should i do?

It depends. How was the pointed object allocated? Does it need to be deallocated manually (i.e. was it allocated dynamically)? *When* should (and when can't) it be deallocated? Who should be responsible for the deallocation (C or C++)? How should it be deallocated (which should directly depend on how it was allocated)?

If the object is static or automatic, then you need to do nothing in particular.

> How to get shared_ptr from raw pointer [from C]?

Assuming the object was allocated in C using `malloc`, and is given to C++ code that is responsible for deallocation, then like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<CTraceSpan> s_span(span, std::free);
```

It is usually bad API design to allocate something, and push the responsibility of figuring out how to deallocate to the client code. So, for every function that allocate something, usually a C API will have a deallocation function that allows the client to decouple from specifics of deallocation. This is particularly important when the allocated object itself has owning pointers dynamic memory.

Assuming `deallocate_ctrace_span` is such deallocation function in this case:

```
std::shared_ptr<CTraceSpan> s_span(span, deallocate_ctrace_span);
```

---

All that said, it appears that your pointers aren't actually allocated in C, but rather C++. Your example isn't complete, and it's unclear how you intend to use the shared pointer.

Comment: sorry for my code isn't complete.  And yes, `server_span` is allocated in C++ by `new`, and deallocate in C++ too.

Answer (score 1):

A `shared_ptr` is for sharing ownership of an object. If it is already owned and managed by someone else, you can pass a reference or non-owning pointer to that object.

If the ownership really *is* shared, you could store a `shared_ptr` in " the vector holding the ParticleEmitter", and then pass copies of that `shared_ptr` so that the very last user will handle the delete.